# SQL - How to get aggregate counts across several columns with the same categories

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a table with multiple columns with the same set of categories. I want to get aggregate counts for the number of times a category shows up within each column. Is there a way to accomplish this with a single select statement?

This is my starting data set:

```
C1  C2  C3
A   ?   A
A   ?   ?
B   ?   A
B   ?   ?
?   B   B
```

I want to get counts by group A & B for columns C1, C2, and C3. The result should look like:

```
Group   C1  C2  C3
A       2   0   2
B       2   1   1
```

I am currently accomplishing this using:

```
Select 
'A' as Group, Count(case when C1 = 'A' then 1 else NULL) as C1...
UNION
Select 
'B' as Group, Count(case when C1 = 'B' then 1 else NULL) as C1...
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2):

This is a slight variation on your structure:

```
select g.grp, 
       sum(case when t.C1 = g.grp then 1 else 0 end) as C1,
       sum(case when t.C2 = g.grp then 1 else 0 end) as C2,
       sum(case when t.C3 = g.grp then 1 else 0 end) as C3
from (select 'A' as grp union all select 'B') g cross join
     t
group by g.grp;
```

The exact syntax might vary depending on your database.

Comment: Just what I was looking for! Thanks for your super fast response.